# VoIp recording solutions (Asterisk or/and FreeSwitch)

Tags: voip, asterisk, recording, voice-recording, freeswitch

currently we're looking for voip recording solution - it must record all incoming/outgoing/internal/conference calls within the company. later on we going to develop applications that let us find/analyze recordings. the main problem as I see at the moment is huge count of calls that is going through the switch (about 1000).

what do u think about using Asterisk or/and FreeSwitch for this task? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

FreeSWITCH would handle 1000 calls just fine.

Comment: even if all of them are recording?

Comment: @jgauffin: I think FreeSwitch is able to route 1000 calls, but probably won't be able to decode RTP and record all of them. That number is probably way less.

Comment: hm... got another details - it could be 18.000 concurent calls!!! what about clustering - will it help if i set up several freeSwitch servers?

Comment: Yes. You would need clustering. FreeSWITCH wiki contains a description of different clustering solutions.

Comment: so I will be able to record 18.000 concurent calls using clustering or it's better to get some separate solution like Oreka?

Comment: Clustering will work fine. But I would not go for a FS/Asterisk solution if you have little voip or linux knowledge. Because it's important to get the configuration correctly. Then it's better to hire a consultant which can configure everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to develop an application to analyze the recordings, do you even need Asterisk or Freewswitch in the equation?  What about using tshark / wireshark to record the RTP streams?

Comment: the thing is that we need "complete" system and one part should be software PBX - so seems it's better to get smthing that already got almost all we need. anyway thx - I'll look at the projects u pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not "can I record the calls?"  With sufficient clustering, you can.  The question is "what are the full requirements of this job?"

Obviously, major requirements and assumptions have not been well-communicated, and for what is obviously a critical system probably government-mandated (or at least important to the company), a proper overall system design to meet the real requirement is needed.  To whit:

What's the reliability requirement?  What happens if a server goes down: are calls lost?  are recordings lost?  What if there's a disk failure?  What's the hardware requirement and budget?  For that matter, what's the budget?  Do you want to separate call routing from recording to help minimize impact if a recorder goes down?  If so, there may be only a few routers, but now failover on those is critically important.  What's the network configuration?  How is network redundancy/failover handled already in the corp?  Where do these recordings get stored and how are they accessed?  How do they get from the recorders to wherever they're stored?  What's the redundancy of that part?  How do you manage all of these?  How many spare servers are needed?  What's the maintenance schedule?

And that's just off-the-cuff questions you need answers to.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Asterisknow or Freepbx has the recording option available. I have not used this feature the web based administration console is showing the options of recording incoming and outgoing calls for particular extensions.

How scalable this is going to be remains to seen?

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that in many countries you're obliged to inform the talking parties if their call is recorded.

recording in FreeSWITCH works just fine, and it's not really demanding to CPU resources. For 1000 simultaneous calls, I think the most concern would be to have a fast enough disk system and enough RAM for i/o cache.

FreeSWITCH opens a new thread for each channel, so the more CPU cores you have, the better. There are some tests with enormous performance results on multicore systems.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source recording service [Oreka](http://oreka.sourceforge.net/). But G711 codec needs license.Its jst nice one.